# Find complexity of the algorithm given?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am not able to find the complexity of this recurrence relation:

T(N) = 2T(N/4)+N^0.51

Comment: I tried master theorum which is giving complexity as theta(n^0.51logn)

Comment: considering p value as 0 but i am little confused about the value of P, So i asked this question here

Comment: I think it have `O(n^0.51)` complexity, because this recurrent relation folds into geometric progression with step equal to `2^(-0.02)`. And because of such near to `1` step, it looks like `O(n^0.51 * log(n))` on practice.

Comment: That actually looks alright. My previous comment was nonsense, apologies. Now you just need to adjust the exponent of your complexity, which is given as log_b(a) in for the form of your equation.

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin which method are u using?

Comment: @KonradRudolph what do think is the complexity?

Comment: Sorry, I think it’s Theta(n^0.51), since 0.51 > log_4(2). It’s “case 3” on the Wikipedia page for the Master theorem.

Comment: yes, I do think so it is  Theta(n^0.51).

Comment: @KonradRudolph This is not enough for case 3, you also need to show *regularity condition* for using case 3. See the last example in [the wikipedia inadmissible equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Inadmissible_equations)

Comment: @amit Yes, I simplified since regularity is trivially satisfied here.

Comment: This is a really good question, but not for this site. It belongs, I think, on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KonradRudolph As a former TA, whenever I see "trivailly", I cringe (thanks for correcting!). I must admit I do sin with it occasionaly, but I think you should show why it's true in this specific case (unless it's research level)

Comment: @amit “cringe”, maybe? And yes, as a former TA myself, I also wouldn’t have accepted that (at least not in CS101, maybe in a later course).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yea, I think it should be cringe. thanks.

Comment: T(N) or T(n) ? get your capitalization straight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [master theorem case 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3), with:

```
a=2, b=4, c=0.51:
```

And since `2*sqrt(n/4) < 2 * (n/4)^0.51`, there is `k<1` such that the regularity condition applies:

```
2 * (n/4)^0.51 < k * n^0.51
```

And since `log_b(a) = log_4(2) = 0.5 < 0.51 = c`

We can conclude that conditions for master theorem case 3 apply, and by the theorem, `T(n)` is in `Theta(f(n)) = Theta(n^0.51)`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, find exact expression for i-th level of our recurrent relation.

For example:

1 level:

[image]

2 level:

[image]

...

i-th level:

[image]

So, now we can express `T(n)` as follows:

[image]

The right sum is geometric decreasing progression and it complexity is `O(1)`.

Because of it, resulting complexity is `O(n^0.51)`.

Comment: Nice, exact solution without Master theorem.